# QuerySet, Object has no attribute id - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to fetch the id of a certain object in Django but I keep getting the following error:

> Exception Value: QuerySet; Object has no attribute id.

My function in views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt  
def check_question_answered(request):
    userID = request.POST['userID']
    markerID = request.POST['markerID']
    title=request.POST['question']
    m = Marker.objects.get(id=markerID)
    u = App_User.objects.get(id=userID) 
    print userID
    print markerID
    print title
    # userID='1'
    # markerID='1'
    # title='Hello'
    at = AttachedInfo.objects.filter(attachedMarker=m.id, title=title)
    print 'user'
    print u.id
    print 'marker'
    print m.id
    print 'att'
    print at
    #print at.id
    if(Answer.objects.filter(marker=m.id, user=u.id, attachedInfo=at.id)):
        print 'pass'
        return HttpResponse('already answered')
    else:
        print 'not'
        return HttpResponse('not answered yet')
```

The error occurs in the if condition in this part (`attachedInfo=at.id`). I checked and when I removed it from the condition, everything started working fine.

Here's models.py:

```
class AttachedInfo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    helpText = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attachedMarker = models.ForeignKey(Marker)
    answer1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    answer2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    answer3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    answer4 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    correctAnswer = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    optionalMessage = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
        
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(App_User)
    app = models.ForeignKey(App, null=True, blank=True)
    marker = models.ForeignKey(Marker)
    attachedInfo = models.ForeignKey(AttachedInfo)
    textAnswer = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    mcqAnswer = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    answered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.attachedInfo.title
```

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error?!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

this line of code

`at = AttachedInfo.objects.filter(attachedMarker=m.id, title=title)`

returns a [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets//)

and you are trying to access a field of it (that does not exist).

what you probably need is

```
at = AttachedInfo.objects.get(attachedMarker=m.id, title=title)
```

Comment: this might throw an error. To handle it gracefully, do a `.filter` amd then `[0]`

Comment: what does it return if queryset has 0 elements?

Comment: you have to check for empty queryset and then do a [0] That is what i meant.

Comment: @EsseTi you're right. I changed filter to get and everything is working great. didn't really think of that.
Thank you very much

Comment: Ok. But be aware that if there's no value it will return an exception.

Comment: @karthikr @EsseTI, filtered queryset now has methods like `first()` and `last()` etc which return object at respective positions.

Answer (score 27):

The reason why you are getting the error is because `at` is a `QuerySet` ie: a list. You can do something like `at[0].id` or use `get` instead of `filter` to get the `at` object.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I used get instead of filter and working great. Thank you very much.

Comment: i stumbled over this and tried the filter and  ''at[0].id''  gives: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'. Maybe you can correct that?

Answer (score 5):

In most cases you do not want to handle not existing objects like that. Instead of

```
ad[0].id
```

use

```
get_object_or_404(AttachedInfo, attachedMarker=m.id, title=title)
```

It is the recommended [Django shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) for that.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error for almost 2 days, the main issue for this error solely depends on two files i.e.

models.py & views.py

I was getting this error because I wanted to create session from email id but it shows their is no attribute email so it wasn't fetching any str object.

Solution:-

models.py

```
class Register(models.Model):
userid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s" %(self.name, self.email)
```

Create a string for the following you want data from according to your project.

views.py

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        emailx1 = request.POST['emailx']
        passwordx1 = request.POST['passwordx']
        if (Register.objects.filter(email=emailx1, password=passwordx1)).exists():
            a = Register.objects.filter(email=emailx1).first()
            request.session['session_name'] = a.email
            request.session['session_id'] = a.userid
            return render(request, "index.html", {"a": a})
```

Use .first() method with your Model.objects method. This have resolved my problem hope it would resolves yours too.