# How do I assign an id/pk number to an existing user?

Tags: python, django

first time poster, new coder. Forgive my ignorance!

I am trying to query the id/pk of users in my user table in the python shell but it is telling me that my users don't have that attribute. I thought that was created automatically?

Since it is clearly not, how do I assign my existing users id numbers and how do I make sure new users are automatically assigned id numbers going forward?

Thanks in advance!

```
>>>user = User.objects.filter(username='alice')
>>>user
<QuerySet [<User: alice>]>
>>>user.id
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'
>>> user.pk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QuerySet, Object has no attribute id - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572569/queryset-object-has-no-attribute-id-django)

Answer (score 1):

Your `user` variable is a `QuerySet`, not a `User` object. `User.objects.filter(...)` returns a `QuerySet`. You can see this because the output resulted in `[<User: alice>]` (a **list**), not `<User: alice>` (a **User**).

Also the error says: "**QuerySet** object has no attribute 'id'" it doesn't say "**User** object has no attribute 'id'". i.e. **read the error**!

In order to get the specific user, use `get()`: `User.objects.get(username='alice')`. Note that `get()` will raise an exception if the object doesn't exist.

Look at the documentation on [**QuerySets**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/) to learn which methods return querysets and which return objects.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was very helpful. I did try reading the error but I'm still learning the ropes.