# How to get all the fields from my model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Here is my Model.py

```
class BlogModel(models.Model):
    blog_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    content = FroalaField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True , null=True , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='public')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    upload_to = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is my View.py

```
def my_blogs(request):
    d = BlogModel.objects.all().filter(user = request.user)
    return render(request,"my_blogs.html",{'message' : d})
```

But when I try to get the blog_id and created_at fields then it will shows an error that the requested fields are not present in the respective table.

But you can see that the field is n the table itself.

Please help
Here is the error i am getting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGv23.png)

Comment: Maybe you forgot (`migrate`) if you hit. Leave the code and error you received

Comment: Did you migrate the database properly?

Comment: I have edited the post with the error i am getting

Comment: `d.blog_id` makes no sense, since a `QuerySet` is a *collection* of objects.

Comment: For sure you did some changes after the first migration. 

You have to repeat makemigrations and migrate command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QuerySet, Object has no attribute id - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572569/queryset-object-has-no-attribute-id-django)

Answer (score 0):

Django Queryset d is a list of objects. You have to loop through it:

```
for each_blog in d:
    each_blog.blog_id
```

This is how you access the data for a filter method query set.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I will try it out in this way

Answer (score 0):

`BlogModel.objects.all().filter(user = request.user)` returns a query set i.e. a list of blogs satisfying the conditions.

You might want to iterate through all the blogs in order to display it, which can be done as follows:

```
{% for blog in d %}
{{ blog.blog_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in **views.py**:

```
from .models import BlogModel

def my_blogs(request):
    blogs = BlogModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'my_blogs.html', locals())
```

In your html template **my_blog.html** try this:

```
{% for b in blogs %}
{{ b.id }}: {{ b.created_at }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write in **views.py**:

```
def my_blogs(request):
    # filtered queryset for login user
    queryset = BlogModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,"my_blogs.html",{'blogs': queryset})
```

and in template **my_blogs.html**:

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
    {{ blog.id }}
    {{ blog.created_at }}
{% endfor %}
```

The BlogModel.objects.filter(user=request.user) returns a queryset which is list of your model objects. You can access object by iterating the queryset in template.