# I am getting Multiple Query set Errors in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am working on an app that keep records of businesses and their employers
Here is my model.py for Employment and Business

```
class Employment(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(
        max_length=128, choices=EMPLOYEE_ROLE_CHOICES, default="EMPLOYEE")
    deduction_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=1028)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    account_balance = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

and Business

```
class Business(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tax_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
    contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contact_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contact_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ForeignKey("main.Image", null=True,
                              blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    json_data = JSONField(blank=True, default=dict)
```

I want to get ids of all the employees with specific business id like this

```
employees =Employment.objects.filter(business=business, active=True)
```

but when I try to get id `employees.id`
I get error

```
In [44]: employees =Employment.objects.filter(business=b, active=True)

In [45]: employees.id

<ipython-input-45-5232553f9273> in <module>
----> 1 employees.id

AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'
```

if I use `get` instead of `filter` suggested by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572569/queryset-object-has-no-attribute-id-django)
I still get error

```
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Employment -- it returned 5!
```

What should I do? Tried everything on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last error you get should give you a good hint about the issue: you are getting multiple results. If you want to see the data, you have to iterate over it:

```py
for employee in employees:
    print(employee.id)
```

Also, if you want only to get all the ids, there is a more performant solution:

```py
ids = list(Employment.objects.filter(business=business, active=True).values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Comment: I did that too ```AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'``` This the error I got

Comment: Weird, you should only get instances of the  model when you iterate over a queryset, are you sure that you weren't printing `employees` in the loop? this would give this error.

Comment: I am doing this 
```
In [59]: E = Employment.objects.filter(business=b, active=True)

In [60]: for e in E:
    ...:     print(E.id)
    ...: 
    ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-840bf4db2e3c> in <module>
      1 for e in E:
----> 2     print(E.id)
      3
      4

AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'

```

Comment: it should be `print(e.id)` (`E` is the whole queryset you are iterating over)