# AttributeError at /check 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: django

i wanted to check whether the name is exists in owner table or not.

this is my models.py

```
class owner(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

this is my index.html
`

```
<form style="color:black" method="POST" action="check" class=" mt-3">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label for="inputText" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Username</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label for="inputText" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-success mb-3" type="submit">Login</button>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger mb-3" href="index">Go Back</a>
                        </form>
```

`this is my urls.py`

```
path('index', views.index),
    path('check', views.check),
```

`this is my views.py`

```
def check(request):

    owners = owner.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        if owners.name == name and owners.password == password :
            return render(request, "card/check.html")
```

`it gives error on this line`

```
 if owners.name == name and owners.password == password :
```

`

how to check whether the name exist or not in table

Comment: What is your model?

Comment: class owner(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Comment: post this as code in the question. Also HINT: what does `print(owners)` output? What does that mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QuerySet, Object has no attribute id - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572569/queryset-object-has-no-attribute-id-django)

Answer (score 0):

```
owners = owner.objects.all() # This line fetches all the record in the owner table and returns queryset object


if owners.name == name and owners.password == password # The queryset can not have a name attribute. Use an instance.
```

Solution:

```
name = request.POST.get('name')
password = request.POST.get('password')
owner = Owner.objects.filter(name=name, password=password).first()
if owner:
    return render(request, "card/check.html")
```