# Receiving "NotImplementedError" when using TruncMonth in Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, mongodb, datetime, django-queryset

I am a complete beginner when it comes to programming and Django.

What I am using:

Django 2.2.8

pymongo 3.12.1

djongo 1.3.6

MongoDB 3.6.23

I am trying to create a queryset in which I take a date from my database and group it by month. The date from the database I am pulling from is formatted as "2022-11-26T00:00:00.000+00:00". So I am trying to annotate a new field of just the month using TruncMonth so that I  can then group by months. I have also tried using "extract" but that doesn't seem to work either.

I am trying to avoid using a method that uses "extra" as it has been deprecated.

I have been doing this in python shell until I get the results I want. Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class Charts(models.Model):
    severity_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    num_findings = models.IntegerField()
    finding_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

python shell:

```
>>>from charts.models import Charts
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
>>>Charts.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('finding_date')).values('month')
```

#Which throws this error

```
    `NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseOperations may require a datetime_trunc_sql() method`
```

From what research I have done, it has something to do with the field being a datetime vs a date I believe. I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572569/queryset-object-has-no-attribute-id-django) that seems to be on the right track but cannot execute.

Another useful piece of info is when I run Charts.objects.values('finding_date') it returns:
`[{'finding_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},` ... etc. So I know the field is a     datetime.datetime.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are in need of an answer, so I'll provide one quickly, though I'm typing this on my phone, so it won't be very detailed.

I think you want to use Extract instead of TruncMonth. See here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#extract

On that page you'll find an example where they extract the year from a datetime field

```py
>>> experiment = Experiment.objects.annotate(
...    start_year=Extract('start_datetime', 'year')).get()
>>> experiment.start_year
2015
```

I'm pretty sure, if you use Extract instead of TruncMonth and use 'month' instead of 'year' everything should work.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the same error when I use extract. Is there a way to convert to datetime.date? Or something in that area of messing with the datetime format?